# Symmetrical image transformation for a kaleidoscope-type image

Tags: image-processing

I've been trying to write a little kaleidoscope-type manipulate, using images rather than graphics, and using `ImageTransformation` as a way in. However, I'm starting to suspect that my approach isn't going to work. Before I abandon it, though, I thought I'd ask here if it can be rescued:

```
im = ImageResize[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}], 100]

Manipulate[
 ImageTransformation[
     ImagePad[im, {{x, -x}, {-x, x}}, Padding -> "Reversed"],
     Function[{pt}, {ArcTan[-#2, #1] & @@ pt, Norm[pt]}], 
   DataRange -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, 
   Padding -> "Reversed"], {x, 0, 100, 5}]
```

[image: a manipulated mandrill]

While the results are OK, it isn't symmetrical, and I'm not sure that the transform can be corrected to make it so?

(Strictly speaking this is a teleidoscope, rather than a kaleidoscope...)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think the main problem is that `ArcTan` runs from $-\pi$ to $\pi$, but the `DataRange` in the `x` direction runs from `0` to `1`, so you're actually using 6 and a bit copies of the original image to cover the whole circle. This is easily fixed by specifying explicit values for `DataRange`, i.e.

```
Manipulate[
 With[{sectors = 8},
  ImageTransformation[
   ImagePad[im, {{-x, x}, {-x, x}}, Padding -> "Reversed"], 
   Function[{pt}, {ArcTan[-#2, #1] & @@ (pt), Norm[pt]}], 250,
   DataRange -> {Pi/sectors {-1, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, Padding -> "Reversed"]], {x, 0, 
  100, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here, `sectors` is the number of sectors in the transformed image.

**Edit**

Note that while `ImageTransformation` works it isn't very fast. If you are using Mathematica 8 you could use for example `ParametricPlot` in combination with `TextureCoordinateFunction` to  get a similar but faster result.

First, we need a source image for the `Texture`. To get the right tiling where two neighbouring images are each other's reflection, I'm using the following:

```
imReflected = ImageAssemble[{
   {ImageReflect[im, Bottom], ImageRotate[im, Pi]},
   {im, ImageReflect[im, Left]}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Next, we need a `TextureCoordinateFunction`. To get the reflections of the shifted image in the circles `r=a` and the radial lines `t=b` where `a` and `b` are integers I'm using a triangle wave with period 2 and amplitude 1/2 which is vertically shifted by some offset corresponding to `x` in the solution above.

```
func[p_, x_] := x + TriangleWave[{0., 1/2.}, p/2 - 1/4]
```

The transformed image can then be plotted according to

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[{r Cos[2 Pi/sectors t], r Sin[2 Pi/sectors t]}, 
    {r, 0, 3}, {t, 0, sectors},
  Mesh -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None,
  Axes -> False,
  PlotStyle -> {Opacity[1], Texture[imReflected]},
  TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({func[#4, x], func[#3, x]} &),
  TextureCoordinateScaling -> False,
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
  PlotPoints -> {4, 1 + Round[40, sectors]},
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}],
 {x, 0, 1},
 {{sectors, 6}, 4, 10, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that for the best result the number of plot points in the `r` and `t` direction should be one plus a multiple of the number of rings and sectors, respectively.

**Edit**

Inspired by faleichik's answer below, I've decided to implement his solution using textured triangles. There are basically two different triangles in the tessellation, one being the mirror image of the other. The other triangles are rotated and/or translated copies of either of these triangles which can be constructed from the base triangles using `Rotate` and `Translate`. Therefore, one way to get the tessellation is as follows:

```
Manipulate[
 DynamicModule[{texcrds, base, hex, im},
  im = ImageResize[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}], 100];

  texcrds = offset + {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}};
  base = {Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}}, 
     VertexTextureCoordinates -> texcrds],
    Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1/2, -Sqrt[3]/2}}, 
     VertexTextureCoordinates -> texcrds]};
  hex = Rotate[base, #, {0, 0}] & /@ {0, 2 Pi/3, -2 Pi/3};

  Graphics[{Texture[im],
    Translate[Translate[hex, {{0, 0}, {3/2, -Sqrt[3]/2}}], 
     Tuples[{3 Range[0, n/2], Range[0, n] Sqrt[3]}]]},
   PlotRange -> {{-1/2, 3 n/2 + 1/2}, {-Sqrt[3]/2, n Sqrt[3]}}]],
 {{n, 3, "resolution"}, 1, 5, 1},
 {{offset, 0}, 0, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks - again - you always solve my problems...! The ParametricPlot approach is great.

Comment: The second one is very nice, using the graphics card to do the interpolation (approximating it with linear segments).  I can't give another +1 unfortunately.

Comment: @Szabolcs thanks. I'm always surprised at how fast Textures are rendered.

Comment: @Heike I hate you! :-) I've been speeding up my code but now it is impossible to beat you.

Comment: So good! Thanks again. That might make a good "wolfram demo" one day...

Answer (score 7):

The topic has intrigued me for a long time, and this question became a final boost for sorting it out.
Let me start from the result itself:

[image][image][image][image]

To see what is going on we should first analyse the structure of real kaleidoscope tesselations. 
Take a kaleidoscope picture from the inet and make some marking:

[image]

So we have six different types of equilaterial triangles which are the reflections of the original (centered) triangle.
Things become easier when we introduce the basis $v=\{v_1,v_2\}$ (red vectors). Note that the marked coordinates on the picture are 
given in this basis.
The periodic structure of tesselation in this basis is simple: its tile is the $[0,3)\times[0,3)$ square (diamond in original 
orthogonal coordinates).

Each tile consists of 9 diamonds combibed from two triangles. There are three types of diamonds (I, II and III), 
the corresponding triangle components are denoted t.1 and t.2, where t is the diamond type.

Now we need some basic yet boring linear algebra to start it all up. At the end we get the function 
`mappt` which for a given point on the plane determines the type of the triangle it belongs to and maps it to the original 
triangle to obtain the required value.

```
v = {v1, v2} = scale {{1, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}} // N;
vI = Inverse@Transpose@v;
patt = a : {a1_, a2_};
a2x[patt] := a1 v1 + a2 v2;
x2a[patt] := vI.a;

tI[patt] := a;
tI[patt /; 1 <= a1 + a2 < 2] := {1 - a2, 1 - a1};
tII[patt] := {1 - a2 - a1, a1};
tII[patt /; 1 <= a1 + a2 < 2] := {a1 + a2 - 1, 1 - a2};
tIII[patt] := {a2, 1 - a2 - a1};
tIII[patt /; 1 <= a1 + a2 < 2] := {1 - a1, a1 + a2 - 1};

tTable = {{tI, tII, tIII}, {tIII, tI, tII}, {tII, tIII, tI}} // 
   Transpose;
gett[patt] := tTable[[Sequence @@ ({1, 1} + Floor@Mod[a, 3])]];
map[patt] := gett[a][(# - Floor@#) &@Mod[a, 3]];

mappt = a2x@map@x2a@# &;
```

To demonstrate the result it is better to get non-symmetric original image so we have to cut the mandrill.

```
im = ImageResize[ImageTake[
   ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}], {150, 450}, {200, 500}], 50]
```

[image]

The object to manipulate is the `scale` which determines the width of the original equilaterial triangle.

```
Manipulate[
  scale = s; 
  ImageTransformation[ im, mappt, 200,
     DataRange -> Automatic,
     AspectRatio -> Automatic,
     PlotRange -> Sqrt[3]/(2 s) {{-1, 2}, {-1, 2}}
  ], 
  {s, .5, 1, .05},
  SynchronousUpdating -> False
]
```

That's it. The only issue now is that this implementation is quite slow.
One might wish to make a compiled version of `mappt`, but I like this particular code pretty much.

Comment: I don't know which version of Mathematica you use, but in version 8 you could speed things up a lot by using a tessellation of textured triangles instead of an image transformation.

Comment: Thanks - this is much closer to the ideal device than I would have reached on my own ! I really like both the answers...